# Localhost, find a local file through web developer tools or other wise

Tags: javascript, wordpress, localhost

I am currently doing an internship, and I have an assignement to fix some javascript, which in itself is very interesting.

However, the site which I am trying to fix (which I have recieved all wordpress files and database) is a complete mess. The file structure is impossible to figure out and when I search for the name (which I learned through webdeveloper tools) it does not appear.

So the question is, can I through webdeveloper tools or other means open up the file folder ?

Comment: You can use node and `fs.readdir` to transverse recursively through all folders to find the file you want. If you're on windows or os x couldn't you just use the built in search functions? Or, you could probably achieve the same thing in bash.

Comment: Problem is, the web developer tools tells the file name is "forhandler", and I did try to search for it, but it does not appear.

So I might try to fs.readdir.

Comment: You could simply do something like `find /absolute/path -name '*.js'` - this will search for all files having a `js` extension in the folder specified by `/absolute/path` and all its subfolders.

Comment: I tried that, and it works to find other files but this. I am starting to think, it might not go by the name which is shown to me in the google webdeveloper tools. Thanks for your support though.

Comment: You should be able to see the file path in the HTML source of the page (ctrl+u in your browser, search for the file name).

Comment: I found a solution. While it is a terrible file structure, it was not the structure at fault. I simply had to empty the cache before it updated itself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would highly recommend adding your last response as an answer so that other people new to development know what to do. Specially when it is easy to blame a platform/developer/file structure when in reality it is a whole different matter.